# LARAVEL Invalid argument supplied for foreach() loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a `Session::get('employee_leave_tag');` that contains the `payroll_leave_employee_id` since `data` is not only one i used a `foreach` loop. But im having an error

***Invalid argument supplied for foreach()***

Can someone help me what's the cause why i am getting this error? Thanks.

```
     public function get_session_leave_tagv2()
     {
          $employee = [0 => 0];
          if(Session::has('employee_leave_tag'))
          {
               $employee = Session::get('employee_leave_tag');
          }

          $empdata = array();
          foreach($employee as $emp)
          {

                 $employee_id = Tbl_payroll_leave_employeev2::select('payroll_employee_id')
                                                          ->join('tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2','tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2.payroll_leave_employee_id','=','tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2.payroll_leave_employee_id')
                                                          ->where('tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2.payroll_leave_employee_id',$emp)
                                                          ->distinct()
                                                          ->get();

                    if(count($employee_id) == 0)
                    {
                         $empa = Tbl_payroll_employee_basic::join('tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2','tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2.payroll_employee_id','=','tbl_payroll_employee_basic.payroll_employee_id')->whereIn('tbl_payroll_leave_employee_v2.payroll_leave_employee_id',$emp)->get();
                         array_push($empdata,$empa);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         $empb = Tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev2::getallemployeeleavedata($employee_id)->get();
                         array_push($empdata,$empb);
                    }                            

          }

          $data['new_record'] = $empdata;

          return json_encode($data);
     }
```

Comment: Please paste the output of $employee array with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two changes in your code.

**1st change:**
Your array declaration `$employee = array();` or `$employee[];`

**2nd change:**
Its always a good practice to check if the variable is an array and not empty using `if` condition before we write `foreach` loop. It will save us from the error which you are facing.

```
if(is_array($employee) && !empty($employee))
{
    foreach($employee as $emp)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your (first change) is declaired in line 3!

Comment: Actually he declaires an array containing one entry array(0=>0); or am I wrong?

Comment: @Dwza, ultimately it seems like he wanted to declare an empty array. If you want to declare array with 0 index then no need to write index 0 explicitly because its by default starts from 0.

Comment: I know, but the parser would not throw an exception because the syntax actually is correct. Guess a var_dump would show an array as well. But it's not realy a declaration of an empty array. More like a bad allocation. Or am I totaly wrong? Im on my phone so I cant realy test it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
if (isset($employee) && count($employee) > 0) {
    if (is_array($employee)) {
        foreach($employee as $emp) {
            //display Array employee
        }
    } else {
        //display for NON Array employee
    }
}
```